How to install a Wix 5 dual scope MSI per user over the same MSI advertised per user?
I created a dual scope MSI project using Wix Toolset 5.0 and I tried to test the following scenario:

advertise the MSI per user:    msiexec.exe /ju Installer.msi /q
install the same MSI per user: msiexec.exe /i Installer.msi

I expected a successful per-user installation without elevation required, but it asked for elevation. Looking into the installation log file, I see the ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER properties are deleted from the beginning of installation and the INSTALLFOLDER is set as a subfolder of the C:\Program Files, in CostFinalize CA.
The only change I made to Wix 5 project template was the attribute Scope="perUserOrMachine" under Package.
So my question is: what I have to write in the installer project so the above scenario work fine? Or do I need to launch msiexec.exe /i command with additional parameters?
